# How to make a phantom applicative functor in PureScript?

Tags: haskell, applicative, purescript, monoids

I'm reading through [this paper](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.pdf) and it says that Monoids are phantom applicative functors.

I tried setting up a phantom type in purescript but I get a type error in the Functor instance.  My guess is the compiler doesn't know what the `a` is in `Accy o a` after doing the map.  How would I fix that?

```hs
newtype Accy o a = Accy { acc :: o }

instance mapaccy :: (Monoid o) => Functor (Accy o) where
  map f (Accy { acc : a }) = Accy { acc : (f a) }

instance maccy :: (Monoid o) => Apply (Accy o) where
  apply (Accy { acc : f }) (Accy { acc : a }) = (Accy { acc : f <> a })

instance mpp :: (Monoid o) => Applicative (Accy o) where
  pure _ = Accy { acc : mempty }

instance msemi :: (Monoid o) => Semigroup (Accy o a) where
  append (Accy { acc : a }) (Accy { acc : b }) = Accy { acc : (a <> b) }


map f (Accy { acc : a }) = Accy { acc : (f a) }
                                           ^
  Could not match type      
    o2      
  with type      
    a0      
  while checking that type t1
    is at least as general as type a0
  while checking that expression a
    has type a0
  in value declaration mapaccy
```

Comment: `Accy o` is a constant functor. `map`ing any function `f : a->b` would yield `map f :: Accy o a -> Accy o b` which should ignore `f` completely, since there's no argument of type `a` around (only `o` is available).

Answer (score 3):

I see my problem.  The map function is mapping over `Accy o` so the `a` in `map :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` is the phantom type which is inaccessable.

Looks like I need to disregard the f in the Functor instance.

```
instance mapaccy :: (Monoid o) => Functor (Accy o) where
  map f (Accy { acc : a }) = Accy { acc : a }
```